# Schengen Visa Sponsorship Letter Format

Tags: schengen-visas

I am looking for Schengen Visa Sponsorship Letter format (Schengen Family Visit Visa for Germany), I wish to write. I am unable to find any information on format on their website.
I can write the same, but curious to know if it is mandatory to write in a particular format?

Comment: I presume you are not talking about a *Verpflichungserklärung*, which is a formal sponsorship by somebody in Germany (who guarantees to reimburse the state for any cost of overstay).

Comment: No, I am not asking about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not talking about a *Verpflichtungserklärung*, then there is no set form or format to follow. Just write a letter in your own words.

Be aware that in this context, for a visit visa, there's really no such thing as sponsoring the *visa application*. At most you're sponsoring your relative's *visit* (that is, providing support so they don't have to fund it all themselves), and the purpose of your letter is to help explain to the consulate how they can afford to go. Nothing more.

In your letter,

- **Do** state exactly which kind of support you'll be providing. Merely a place to sleep? Meals? Travel costs?  If you will spend money out of pocket, state how much, and if it's not an insignificant amount, explain how you can afford that.
- **Do** explain what your relation to the applicant is, and why you would want to support *their* visit in particular.
- **Do** explain a bit about your own circumstances in the host country. In particular, if you're not a citizen, be particular about which permission to live there you have. Also state at least briefly how you make a living -- they're not going to look at that very closely, but they will like to know that you're not owning or managing a business that could benefit from employing your relative illegally.
- **Do not** attempt to promise that your relative will leave the Schengen area after the visit. You can't know that better than the relative themself, and the consulate has no reason to believe you more than they believe the relative saying so directly to them.
- **Do not** bother to make the letter look like an "invitation" and pretending it's not written for the benefit of the consulate. Starting with "to whom it may concern" (or its German equivalent) is quite fine.
- **Avoid** sounding like the consular officer would be doing *you* a favor by approving the visa, even if you would like that to happen. They don't care, and don't owe you any favors. Your role is to *provide information* for deciding the application, not to let your own good standing with the immigration authorities substitute for the applicant's